# Loop over multiple .csv files python/pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two folders that contain +50 .csv files, I want to process al those files in my python code with pandas. At the beginning of my code I load two different .csv files:

```
Location1 = path\tasks_01.csv'          
Location2 = path\resource_01.csv'          

dftask = pd.read_csv(Location1)
dfresource = pd.read_csv(Location2)
```

In the middle I do all kind of different operations to structure the data etc. At the end I save both .csv files to a new .csv file:

```
dftask.to_csv(path\tasks_new.csv')
dfresource.to_csv(path\resource_new.csv')
```

Since I have two folders, one containts the task.csv files and the other the resource.csv files how can I edit my code in such a way I can loop over all those files? And save them under their original name?

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of files in each folder and then zip through both of them.

```
import os

files_in_folder_1 = [os.path.join(path1, f) for f in os.listdir(path1) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path1, f))]

files_in_folder_2 = [os.path.join(path2, f) for f in os.listdir(path2) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path2, f))]

for file1, file2 in zip(files_in_folder_1, files_in_folder_2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
        ...
```

Comment: can you explain in further detail how I should do that?

Comment: I submitted my answer too quickly, I've added some more information.

Comment: Oke ;) But can you also show how I should edit the dftask and dfresource, dataframes? Or is f1 = location1 and f2=location2 ? And how should I change the last line of code to save the files?

Comment: `dftask = pd.read_csv(file1)       dfresource = pd.read_csv(file2)     ......     dftask.to_csv(file1)           dfresource.to_csv(file2)`

Comment: how should I define path1 and path2? I am trying to do:

path1 = 'C:\\...................'
path2 = 'C://................'

Unfortunately this does not work..

Comment: `path1` and `path2` should be a path to a folder, not a file, ie `r'C:\SomeFolder'`

Comment: Oke, thank's! However I get the following error: 

IndentationError: expected an indented block


After f2: there is a red line..

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code with the indented block error, any idea how I can solve this problem?